# Spring Data JPA with Postgres issue with modifying a column dynamically

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here's my @Query decorated method meant for updating a column with a new value. The column name is not fixed and is passed as an argument.

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value="UPDATE user SET :column=:newValue WHERE id=:id",nativeQuery = true)
fun partialUpdate(@Param("id") id: String,@Param("column") column: String, @Param("newValue")newValue: String): Int
```

Here's the stack trace

```
2021-04-01T15:18:03,396Z [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2021-04-01T15:18:03,396Z [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 19
2021-04-01T15:18:03,442Z [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 19
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

JPA doesn't support passing the column name as an argument. Use CriteraAPI Instead

```
@Transactional
    fun partialUpdate(id: String, column: String, newValue: String):Int {
        val cb: CriteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder()
        val update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(User::class.java)
        val user = update.from(User::class.java)
        update.set(user.get(column), newValue).where(cb.equal(user.get<String>("id"), id))
        return em.createQuery(update).executeUpdate()
    }
```